# How to paste a number + 1 from a column in a df in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, repeat, paste

I have a df with some information in which I have created some testcases. I would like to paste the testcases together to a SQL-sentence, with +1 added to a specific number for each case.

I first create the testcases:

```
z <- data.frame(X = c('1','0', '1','1', '1'), Y = c('1','0', '1','0', '1'))

z <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(z), function(x) 
  ifelse(z[[x]] != '?', paste(colnames(z)[x], ' = ', z[[x]]),'')))

z$testcases <- do.call(paste, c(z, sep=" AND "))
```

I try to add 1 to the number '1200', by a +1 function I have created, however I can't figure out how to make R use the first number, and then paste the number + 1 in the next row:

```
add_1 <- function(x) {
  y <- x+1
  return(y)
}

id_str <- 1200

z$test_sql <- paste0("WHEN ", z$testcases , " THEN ", "'", id_str + add_1(id_str), " passed","'")

#expected output for z$test_sql:

z$test_sql
[1] "WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 AND X  =  1 & Y  =  1 THEN '1200 passed'"
[2] "WHEN X  =  0 AND Y  =  0 AND X  =  0 & Y  =  0 THEN '1201 passed'"
[3] "WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 AND X  =  1 & Y  =  1 THEN '1202 passed'"
[4] "WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  0 AND X  =  1 & Y  =  0 THEN '1203 passed'"
[5] "WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 AND X  =  1 & Y  =  1 THEN '1204 passed'"
```

Comment: What is `testid`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. See edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z$test_sql <- paste0("WHEN ",z$V1," AND ",z$V2," AND ",z$testcases," THEN ","'",id_str+0:(nrow(z)-1)," passed","'")

                                                             test_sql
1 WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 AND X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 THEN '1200 passed'
2 WHEN X  =  0 AND Y  =  0 AND X  =  0 AND Y  =  0 THEN '1201 passed'
3 WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 AND X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 THEN '1202 passed'
4 WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  0 AND X  =  1 AND Y  =  0 THEN '1203 passed'
5 WHEN X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 AND X  =  1 AND Y  =  1 THEN '1204 passed'
```